# Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed NotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to a required path

Tags: permissions, packaging, anaconda, source-packages

When i am trying to install any library such as pandas and even when i tried to install clean package using `conda install anaconda-clean`.
it gives an error :

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

NotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to a required path.
  path: /home/parth/.conda/pkgs/urls.txt
  uid: 1000
  gid: 1000

If you feel that permissions on this path are set incorrectly, you can manually
change them by executing

  $ sudo chown 1000:1000 /home/parth/.conda/pkgs/urls.txt

In general, it's not advisable to use 'sudo conda'.
```

Comment: Hi @user11908262, do you figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting this error as you don't have permission. **conda** command doesn't work with sudo.
To fix this error i gave permission to anaconda folder by changing ownership.

```
 $ sudo chown -R myuser /home/myuser/anaconda3
```

Comment: Hi @Dev, this did not work for me.